# What happened to snap Dekko?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, snap

I've been using snap Dekko Mail as my everyday mail client for a while now. After reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04, the snap find command can't find Dekko. Anybody know what happened to it? Thanks.

delta1071

Answer (score 0):

I see the following:

1. The Dekko 2 application is available [in OpenStore](https://open.uappexplorer.com/app/dekko2.dekkoproject) it is named *app/dekko2.dekkoproject* here and was

   > Updated: December 31st 2018
2. The [download page on its official site](https://dekkoproject.org/download/) suggests the following installation procedure of the Snap package:

   ```
   snap install ubuntu-app-platform
   snap install --edge --devmode dekko
   ```

   but it fails on last command:

   > ```
   > $ snap install --edge --devmode dekko
   > error: snap "dekko" not found
   > ```

   Moreover `snap find dekko` does not produce results.
3. Searching on SnapCraft.io Store [also fails](https://snapcraft.io/search?category=&q=dekko).

So you should open Issue on [Dekko's GitLab account](https://gitlab.com/dekkoproject/dekko/issues) about missed Snap.

Comment: Thanks for responding N0rbert. The Dekko 2 app is an Ubuntu Touch version which I am currently running on my old Nexus. I've reported the issue to the Dekko team.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the show, but just in case someone else searches the answer to your question.
- Rogier Oudshoor recently fixed Dekko 2 snap packaging. You can get the snap here: https://snapcraft.io/install/dekko2/ubuntu
- Beside that, be aware further development of dekko takes place here: https://gitlab.com/dekkan/dekko/